# Identifying various parts

Tags: part-identification

I bought a lot of various parts, but I can't seem to identify the following parts.

- The grey wheels have rubber on one side of the axl hole
- I'm thinking that that the black frame-thing isn't Lego, but wanted to be sure before tossing it.
- The white wheels have circular holes, not axl holes.

[image: Parts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6 black parts on the left *might* me (used):
[Tire 14mm D. x 9mm Smooth Small Wide Slick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30028&name=Tire%2014mm%20D.%20x%209mm%20Smooth%20Small%20Wide%20Slick&category=%5BTire%20&%20Tread%5D#T=C)

Answer (score 4):

- I can't identify the black parts.
- The toothed wheel is a [string reel spool](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2585).
- The rest of the parts appear to have come from a Robotics Invention System set from RCX-era Mindstorms:

  - The grey wheels with a different material on the inside are [part 2983](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2983). None of those sets have 5 of these, though.
  - The grey bricks are [touch sensors](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=879).
  - The white wheels are [conveyer belt wheels](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32007).